# Login page gone

Tags: magento-1.9, login

My website was working fine but suddenly today login page gone.

It is showing blank page and address is

```
domain.com/customer/account/login/
```

Showing blank white screen

What happen I dont know

Anyone please help.

Comment: check for any error / exception in var/log

Comment: Also check your server `error.log` file.

Comment: you can enable web developer mode on and check log files as well for the detail error

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just on display error in domain.com/index.php like

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');
```

then I got the errors and I solved it.

And I increase the memory limit like

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Then I got page back on the screen.

For more detail
[magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217)